# Get all dom nodes from d3 selection

Tags: d3.js

`selection.node()` returns [only the first](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) node. Can we get an array of all nodes from a selection?

**EDIT** Added some code to help us.

- The attempt with `each()` is the only one producing the wanted
  output, although quite verbose.
- Calling `sel[0]` also returns an array with DOM nodes, but it's hacky  (depends on the internal structure of the library) and includes an unwanted "parentNode" field.

```js
// creating a selection to experiment with
var data= [1,2,3,4]
var sel = d3.select("li")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("li").html(identity);
function identity(d){return d}
console.log(sel); // array[1] with array[4] with the <li>'s 

// using .node()
var res1 = sel.node();
console.log(res1); // first <li> only

// using .each() to accumulate nodes in an array
var res2 = [];
function appendToRes2(){
 res2.push(this);
}
sel.each(appendToRes2);
console.log(res2); // array[4] with the <li>'s (what I want)

// calling sel[0]
var res3 = sel[0];
console.log(res3); // array[4] with the <li>'s plus a "parentNode"

// @thisOneGuy's suggestion
var res4 = d3.selectAll(sel);
console.log(res4); // array[1] with array[1] with array[4] with the <li>'s
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2** Why do I want to do that?
To call [array methods](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays) like `reduce` and `map` on the DOM nodes. D3 provides `filter` but to use others I first need to extract the node array from the selection.

Comment: What about selection.each(function). It's in the link you provided

Comment: yes, I could call `each`, get the dom nodes from `this` and accumulate them in an external variable. It seems that `selection[0]` also does the same. I wonder if there isn't a cleaner/easier way though.

Comment: d3.selectAll(selection) ? Add some code so I can understand your problem better

Comment: @thisOneGuy code added

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer you were hoping for but I believe this is expected. If you look at the [Operating on Selections in the Selection documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#operating-on-selections), it mentions "_why a single-element selection looks like [[node]] rather than [node]_"

Comment: @aug your comment explains some of the results in my code snippet, like `sel` and `sel[0]`, thanks for that. I tried adding more clues to what i'm hoping for under "EDIT 2".

Comment: Using `.each()` is the way I usually do this.  You can't rely on `sel[0]` for the reasons stated [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#group).  If it bothers you this much, there's some good news, [in the upcoming v4 release, it looks like Bostock's going to include a method to do just this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_nodes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I originally wrote this as a comment, but decided to turn it into an answer...*

It looks like d3 v4 will [include the functionality you want](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_nodes).  If you don't want to wait, you can steal the [implementation now](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/nodes.js) and add it to the selection prototype:

```
 d3.selection.prototype.nodes = function(){
   var nodes = new Array(this.size()), i = -1;
   this.each(function() { nodes[++i] = this; });
   return nodes;
 }
```

---

Usage example:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.nodes = function(){
  var nodes = new Array(this.size()), i = -1;
  this.each(function() { nodes[++i] = this; });
  return nodes;
}


var data= [1,2,3,4]
var sel = d3.select("li")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("li").html(identity);
function identity(d){return d}

console.log(sel.nodes());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Since it came from @mbostock, it's a good bet is the best implementation available.

Comment: But this approach also uses `.each()`, right? By building a new array, it is basically the same as OP's `appendToRes2()`. Because it uses an array of predefined size instead of pushing to an array, it might be slightly more efficient, though.

Comment: @altocumulus, yes, it is the same.  I wrote it up as an answer because it's the way the author of `d3` has done it in the upcoming v4 release.  You can't get much more authoritative then that on the "right way to do it".